# How to add a synclient command to rc.local?

Tags: startup, touchpad, synaptics

If I just put `synclient string=value` in `rc.local` it doesn't work. Do I need an `echo` to someplace or is `rc.local` not the place to do this?

Answer (score 3):

As read elsewhere, you can't. rc.local executes before X starts, and synclient needs X.

A workaround is adding the command to startup applications:

```
bash -c "synclient string=value"
```

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1786863&page=3

Answer (score 0):

Run the command directly on startup(startup applications), or put them in a script which you run on startup.